# How to match \Q and \E in Java regex?

Tags: java, regex

I want to match `\Q` and `\E` in a Java regex. 
I am writing a program which will compute the length of the string, matching to the pattern (this program assumes that there is no any quantifier in regex except {some number}, that's why the length of the string is uniquely defined) and I want at first delete all expressions like `\Qsome text\E`. 
But regex like this:

```
"\\Q\\Q\\E\\Q\\E\\E"
```

obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Pattern.quote(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String s = "\\Q\\Q\\E\\Q\\E\\E";
String escaped = Pattern.quote(s);
```

Answer (score 5):

Just escape the backslashes.  The sequence `\\\\` matches a literal backslash, so to match a literal `\Q`:

```
"\\\\Q"
```

and to match a literal `\E`:

```
"\\\\E"
```

You can make it more readable for a maintainer by making it obvious that each sequence matches a single character using `[...]` as in:

```
"[\\\\][Q]"
```